# Visual Studio Team Services Continuous Integration: NuGet Restore Task Failed

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-devops, nuget-package-restore, azure-pipelines

I am using Continuous Integration feature in Team Services (was Visual Studio Online). My build definition targets a specific project in a solution (not the whole solution), which is ClientUI MVC website.

The solution contains three projects:

1. ClientUI
2. AdminUI
3. Client Services

[image]

The Build Definition for ClientUI Project:

**Repository**:

[image]

**Nuget Installer** Step:
I have tried different params but not working.
[image]

**Visual Studio Build**

[image]

Before trying to target the a single project, my build definition was targeting the whole solution with the following parameters:

1. NuGet Installer -> *Path to Solution*: **\*.sln
2. Visual Studio Build -> *Solution*: **\*.sln  ; *MSBuild Arguments*:  /p:outdir=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)

It was working. However now, it generates this error in the Nugget Restore Task:

```html
2016-04-22T21:07:00.6716725Z Set workingFolder to default: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.98.1\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.25
2016-04-22T21:07:00.8163908Z Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.98.1\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.25\NuGetInstaller.ps1


2016-04-22T21:07:01.5283529Z ##[error]Cannot find path 'C:\a\1\s\packages.config' because it does not exist.
2016-04-22T21:07:01.5439897Z C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.98.1\agent\worker\tools\NuGet.exe restore "C:\a\1\s\packages.config"  -NonInteractive


2016-04-22T21:07:03.0441507Z MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.


2016-04-22T21:07:03.0597010Z ##[error]Cannot determine the packages folder to restore NuGet packages. Please specify either -PackagesDirectory or -SolutionDirectory.
2016-04-22T21:07:03.0909881Z ##[error]Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe
```

Comment: Well, is there a packages.config in the ClientUI folder? Have you tried mapping the packages folder at the solution level?

Comment: yes, packages.config exists in the ClientUI folder. That's what I am specifying in the Nugget Installer. I have tried the ***\\*.sln* also didn't work.

Comment: I meant adding the packages folder which seems to be in the same parent as client Ui to the mapped folders on your repository configuration.

Comment: I changed the repository configuration, and added a new mapping with _ServerPath_: '$/MySite/BerkeleyWeb/packages' and  _LocalPath_: 'packages', also the changed the _LocalPath_ for the first mapping to be 'ClientUI'. However the nugget task failed with following errors:  _##[error]The property DirectoryName does not exist or was not found.
 ##[error]Cannot locate a solution file.
##[error]Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe_

Comment: mapping to sln file works for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting "Installation type" to "Install" for "Nuget Installer" task since you are using "packages.config" to install the packages.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Eddie. After changing it to "Install", The "Nugget Install" step runs successfully, however the "Build Solution" gives an error:" _This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props._". However, in the Nugget Install step log i find that it is already added: "_Added package 'Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0' to folder 'C:\a\1\s'_".

Comment: @h.salman The package isn't installed into "packages" folder. Try to add "-OutputDirectory ..\packages" in "Nuget arguments".

Answer (score 4):

For anyone curious, the source of the error about "Please specify either -PackagesDirectory or -SolutionDirectory" is that the build process is trying to issue a command similar to this:

```
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\4.4.1\x64\nuget.exe restore D:\a\1\s\MyProject\packages.config -PackagesDirectory packages -Verbosity Detailed -NonInteractive
```

The below screenshots should help if you want to build a project (rather than the solution) and your nuget "packages" folder is at the solution-level.

Additionally, you may need to specify this as the "MSBuild Argument" in the build task of your project: /p:SolutionDir="/"

[image: The csproj is your "solution."]

[image: If your "packages" folder is at the solution-level, then you want to have that as the Destination directory.]

Comment: Maybe you should clarify what the issue is with the command that you've shown. Also, how exactly does the screenshot help? You should describe this.

Comment: The above screenshots helped me in exactly the same situation: I only needed to restore packages for 1 project among many in solution.
The cure can be seen at the bottom of last screenshot:
specify the Destination directory to "packages"

That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing sorted it out by changing the mapping - go to Repository tab, I had my mapping to another directory which means the nuget installer could not execute.