# Cannot build only one project of a solution in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to create a new build pipeline using Azure Devops. I can built the whole solution, however I am not able to build for a single project in the same solution.

I am getting the following error:

> The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Cannot determine the packages folder to restore NuGet packages. Please specify either -PackagesDirectory or -SolutionDirectory.) Packages failed to restore

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Did you look up on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803687/visual-studio-team-services-continuous-integration-nuget-restore-task-failed

Comment: I updated the post title since the post is not asking how to build only one project. The post asking the solution how to fix the problem of only one project not building. The title of the post is completely misguiding...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Build only one project of a solution in Azure Devops

To resolve this issue, you should **specify a directory for nuget to save the restore nuget packages**, like:

[image]

When I restore the nuget packages for one project by `packages.config`/project file, we should expend the option Advanced on the nuget restore task, then specify a directory, I set it as default packages, `..\packages`. Then I test it, it restored successfully:

```
2019-02-01T06:18:22.1311238Z ##[section]Starting: NuGet restore

....

2019-02-01T06:18:28.3155511Z [command]C:\VSTS-vs2017-agent\_work\_tool\NuGet\4.3.0\x64\nuget.exe restore C:\VSTS-vs2017-agent\_work\5\s\TestSample\TestSample\TestSample.csproj -PackagesDirectory ..\packages -Verbosity Detailed -NonInteractive -ConfigFile C:\VSTS-vs2017-agent\_work\5\Nuget\tempNuGet_169.config

2019-02-01T06:18:37.0366771Z All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
2019-02-01T06:18:37.0594978Z ##[section]Finishing: NuGet restore
2019-02-01T06:18:22.1311238Z ##[section]Starting: NuGet restore
2019-02-01T06:18:22.1319968Z ==============================================================================
2019-02-01T06:18:37.0366199Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\bin\msbuild.exe "C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\svd0ok2h.e2f.nugetinputs.targets" /t:GenerateRestoreGraphFile /nologo /nr:false /v:q /p:NuGetRestoreTargets="C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\bhkdd2rf.itk.nugetrestore.targets" /p:RestoreTaskAssemblyFile="C:\VSTS-vs2017-agent\_work\_tool\NuGet\4.3.0\x64\nuget.exe" /p:RestoreConfigFile="C:\VSTS-vs2017-agent\_work\5\Nuget\tempNuGet_169.config" /p:RestorePackagesPath="..\packages"
2019-02-01T06:18:37.0366350Z 
2019-02-01T06:18:37.0366771Z All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
2019-02-01T06:18:37.0594978Z ##[section]Finishing: NuGet restore
```

The **reason** for the error:

When we only build or restore the nuget package for one project of a solution in Azure Devops, nuget restore the nuget packages to the default `\packages` folder under the solution folder, but since we do not specify the `.sln` file in the build/nuget restore task, nuget does not know where is the solution folder. Then nuget will throw that error. So, we should specify a directory for nuget to save the restore nuget packages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I cannot find that `Destination Directory`

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT yes i have undeleted it and added more info. I need to do it in vsts now

Comment: @HariHaran, Got it, I will check it, then try to resolve it ASAP.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT i still get **undefined** error even after changing `$(SolutionDir)` to `$(ProjectDir)..\`

Comment: This is the solution indeed. The variable name on the task interface is not that straightforward, and took some time to figure out that the "Destination directory" is the equivalent of the -PackagesDirectory flag from the error message.